# paperclip processors in rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ffmpeg, paperclip, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to upload mp3s to S3 using paperclip which works fine, but when I try using a custom processor to create a lower quality audio file I run into problems.

It seems to work, but instead of outputting the whole song in 128k, it only does the first 6 seconds.  (it works fine when i try using ffmpeg at the command line) And it does it for both "styles" not just the snippet style, the original gets processed as well which I don't want.

## song.rb

```
class Song < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :record

  #after_save :create_metadata

  Paperclip.interpolates :record_id  do |attachment, style|
    attachment.instance.record_id
  end

  has_attached_file :mp3,
    :styles => { 
      :snippet => { :processors => [:audio_prehear] } 
    },
    :storage => 's3',
    :s3_credentials => "#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/s3_credentials.yml"....
```

## My processor

```
module Paperclip
  class AudioPrehear < Processor
    attr_accessor :resolution, :whiny
    def initialize(file, options = {}, attachment = nil)
      super
      @file = file
      @whiny = options[:whiny].nil? ? true : options[:whiny]
      @basename = File.basename(@file.path, File.extname(@file.path))
    end
    def make
      target = File.dirname(@file.path) + "/" + @basename + ".mp3"
      convert File.expand_path(file.path), target
      dst = File.open target
    end
    def convert (infile, outfile)
      cmd = "-y -i #{infile} -ab 128k #{outfile}"
      begin
       success = Paperclip.run('ffmpeg', cmd)
      rescue PaperclipCommandLineError
        raise PaperclipError, "There was an error processing the preview for #{@basename}" if whiny
      end
    end
  end
end
```

## log

```
[paperclip] ffmpeg -y -i /var/folders/Ue/UehOEbyxHkS9voyeIiUx3++++TI/-Tmp-/stream20101223-93966-18vy7po-0.mp3 -ab 128k /var/folders/Ue/UehOEbyxHkS9voyeIiUx3++++TI/-Tmp-/stream20101223-93966-18vy7po-0.mp3 2>/dev/null
....

[paperclip] Saving attachments.
[paperclip] saving music/7635/snippet/monkey.mp3
[paperclip] saving music/7635/original/monkey.mp3
....
```

Comment: That's odd. Six seconds, every time? Where are you hosting the app? I ask because some shared hosting providers will kill processes that utilize too many resources. The time is what's making me think it could be some sort of policy limitation.

Comment: Yes it is, always six seconds.  No host, haven't gotten that far.  It's killing it locally on my computer.  When I run FFMPEG directly from the console using the same options, it works fine.

Comment: It also bothers me that the processor also affects the original even though I only call it on the "snippet"

Comment: Have you tried rescuing all exceptions, not just the PaperclipCommandLineError?

Comment: What happens if you run your command from the command line directly?

Comment: @plang, From the command line it works perfectly. @cdmwebs Good suggestion.  I'll try that.

Comment: @cdmwebs, I changed it to rescue everything but there is no error.  It claims to execute fine.  No idea what's going on.

Comment: I know this question is over a year old, but did anyone find anything further? :P

Comment: If it's worth anything, I ended up opting for `lame` to do all of the audio transcoding in my current client project.  It produced the desired functionality, and didn't raise a Cocaine::CommandLine error.